# Windows Server Receiving Blank Files

Tags: windows-server-2008, ubuntu, ftp

Whenever we ftp batch files from our Ubuntu Computer to Windows Server 2008, all the files that are under 1kb are blank.

Files over 1kb are fine, only files under 1kb are affected and only if we ftp batch.

The files are ASCII, we are sending them BINARY.

FTP server is standard Window Server 2008 R2 FTP Client is Standard Ubuntu.

Comment: are you trasnferring the files as ASCII or BINARY?

Comment: Which FTP server and which FTP client are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isolate the problem by:

1. Trying another FTP client
2. FTPing from your Ubuntu computer to another FTP server.

If you use the console to FTP you can turn on [hash mark printing](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/guestftp/4.3.1.html). Turn on hash mark printing and see if this makes any difference, e.g., can you see the hash marks? In general FTP does not 'just break down' when you have two robust operating systems as you describe so there has to be something unique to your environment, but before we can give a sensible reply you will have to isolate the problem further.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, we discovered after trying another FTP client that the problem was in the program to collect files from the stores rather than with FTP batch.